# ValueError: Length of values (1) does not match length of index (3)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to run this piece of code:

```
 df['ID'] =df.groupby(["Code","Number"]).apply(lambda x: x['O'].isin(x['D']) | x['D'].isin(x['O']) & (x['O'] != x['D'])).values
```

with the following input:

```
data1 ={"Code":["A","A","A"], "Number":[7,7,7],"O":["BR","AC","BR"],"D":["AC","LF","LF"]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

I get the following error, if I have only one group (on Code & Number) in the input data frame:

```
data = array([[ True,  True, False]])
index = Int64Index([0, 1, 2], dtype='int64')
ValueError: Length of values (1) does not match length of index (3)
```

If I use another input with multiple rows and groups, I don't get any errors. I don't really understand what's the problem and how can I fix it.

Comment: umm... could you provide some insight into the code

Comment: @Anony Mous The code, create a Boolean column, True if the rows are diagonally equal. so for example the first two rows are True because they have AC in common. False, if not, like the third row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the error because there is a single group.

Example (using a function for clarity):

```
def f(x):
    out = x['O'].isin(x['D']) | x['D'].isin(x['O']) & (x['O'] != x['D'])
    # print(out) # uncomment to see how the groups are handled
    return out

data1 ={"Code":["A","A","A"], "Number":[7,7,7],
        "O":["BR","AC","BR"],"D":["AC","LF","LF"]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

df1.groupby(["Code","Number"]).apply(f)

                0     1      2
Code Number                   
A    7       True  True  False
```

Now let's add another group:

```
data2 = {"Code":list('AAABBB'), "Number":[7,7,7,8,8,8],
         "O":["BR","AC","BR","BR","AC","BR"],"D":["AC","LF","LF","BR","AC","LF"]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

df2.groupby(["Code","Number"]).apply(f)

Code  Number   
A     7       0     True
              1     True
              2    False
B     8       3     True
              4     True
              5     True
dtype: bool
```

You can "fix" the first output with `stack`:

```
df1.groupby(["Code","Number"]).apply(f).stack()

Code  Number   
A     7       0     True
              1     True
              2    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Weird how come you add a second group of data, it starts to stack the 'ids', but not with a single group?

Comment: @INGl0R1AM0R1 I agree, but on the other side, should you use `groupby` with a single group? ;)

Comment: A good point, hahahah

Answer (score 1):

Well from what i could see this line of code return the following output

```
df.groupby(["Code","Number"]).apply(lambda x: x['O'].isin(x['D']) | x['D'].isin(x['O']) & (x['O'] != x['D'])).values

[[ True False  True]]
```

This is actually in the following shape (1,3) if you convert it into numpy or series(which is gonna happen when you ran the following line df['Id'] = your_code) the thing is pandas gives you that error because your output returns a kinda of crooked shaped list. So all you need to do is convert it into numpy and reshape it like this.

```
Id = df.groupby(["Code","Number"]).apply(lambda x: x['O'].isin(x['D']) | x['D'].isin(x['O']) & (x['O'] != x['D'])).values

df['Id'] = np.reshape(np.array(Id),(3,1))
```

I am not sure if this is gonna run with your full dataset, but hey at least you can run when you have one sole row